# Select foreign values from a set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

i got 3 tables attendees, testusers and tasks, where attendees connects testusers&tasks via a many-to-many relation. now my question: why is it possible to retrieve all the ids via "test.ids" but not the testuser_ids via "test.testuser_ids" (as seen in the rails console output below)?

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141027151350) do

  create_table "attendees", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "task_id"
    t.integer  "testuser_id"
    t.boolean  "participate"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "tasks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "task_date"
    t.boolean  "participate"
  end

  create_table "testusers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end    
end
```

rails console:

```
irb(main):030:0> test = Attendee.all
  Attendee Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "attendees".* FROM "attendees"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Attendee id: 1, task_id: 1, testuser_id: 1, participate: true, created_at: "2014-10-29 16:29:43", updated_at: "2014-10-29 16:29:43">, #<Attendee id: 2, task_id: 1, testuser_id: 2, participate: true, created_at: "2014-10-29 16:29:43", updated_at: "2014-10-29 16:29:43">, #<Attendee id: 3, task_id: 1, testuser_id: 3, participate: nil, created_at: "2014-10-29 16:29:43", updated_at: "2014-10-29 16:29:43">, #<Attendee id: 4, task_id: 1, testuser_id: 4, participate: nil, created_at: "2014-10-29 16:29:43", updated_at: "2014-10-29 16:29:43">]>
irb(main):031:0> test.ids
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "attendees"."id" FROM "attendees"
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):032:0> test.testuser_ids
NoMethodError: undefined method `testuser_ids' for #<Attendee::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000106011ab0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible because by default Rails don't provide it as you want.
Even I'm not sure I got what you want to do, but I think one of these is your solution:

```
Attendee.all.first.testusers.ids
```

This will get all the testusers ids from a specific attendee.
Instead, if you want ALL testusers ids from ALL attendees, you will need a loop:

```
res = []
Attendee.all.each { |a| res += a.testusers.ids }
res.uniq
```

Comment: Just a short comment to your answer. Instead of `Attendee.all.each {}`, you can use simply use `Attendee.pluck(:testuser_id)`. Loading all fields of attendees and then iterating over all records is a big overhead here.

Comment: Nice advice :) I didn't have performance in mind writing the answer, but yeah, your comment definitely makes sense.

Comment: thanks a lot! works just fine - even though i don't get why i can't access the test-array in a normal way :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing association for your `Attendee` model. It should have:

```
class Attendee

  belongs_to :testuser

end
```

Besides that you cannot call `Attendee.first.testuser_ids` since `attendees` table is having `testuser_id`. Otherwise change your model schema.

Comment: could you explain this to me? my attendee class had already the belongs_to :testuser & belongs_to :task set! what i don't get is that i receive an array of attendees when i type "test = Attendee.all" but why is it possible to get the ids but it's not possible to get the testuser_ids? - i'm not so familiar with databases - so it's possible that i just didn't get something right ...

Comment: OK, let's start from scratch. `test = Attendee.all` gives you simply all attendees. Now, if you would type `test.class`, you'll see `Attendee::ActiveRecord_Relation` (I assume you're using at least Rails 4.0 - it's important here). If you want to get only testuser_id, you would type `Attendee.pluck(:testuser_id)` (the preffered way). If you don't like it, it's also possible to type `Attendee.all.collect(&:testuser_id)` (worse performance, cause you're fetching complete records whereas only `testuser_id` is needed).

Comment: Finally, to answer your question why you can't type `Attendee.all.testuser_ids`. You can't, because `Attendee.all` returns a collection (its type is `Attendee::ActiveRecord_Relation`), not a single object. It would be possible if you'd have an association `has_many testusers`. However, it is pointless here. What you should learn is what is a collection and what you can do with it and what is a single object. This page: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html is really helpful and will let you understand it, I hope.

Comment: you're the best! thanks a lot! i was exactely the difference between an array and a collection that got me confused!